# Dialog box inside terminal. Can't get rid of it no matter what

Tags: command-line, apt, virtualbox, kubuntu

[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem.]

I have tried enter, y, clicking  nothing works. How do I get rid of this dialog box?

Comment: Press `Tab` until you reach `ok` then `enter`.

Comment: That worked. Thnx